# How do I match and post id to a comment in mongoose populate for find({})

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I am trying to get comments from one collections and link them to their specific post.

What I want to do is find all of the posts instead of the collections THEN populate each of the commentid's in post collections with matching comments inside the comment collections.

I have set articleid to be the same as the post _id manually with an an ajax request function. However I am getting confused with how to properly use match in populate.

Ex. post _id 123, I want all comments with articleid, 123, but for multiple id's not just one.

I looked at the mongoose docs about populate and there wasn't anything as in depth as this example.

```js
router.get('/displayPosts', (req, res) => {

 Post.find({}, 'topic title url', () => {
    })
      .populate({
        path: 'commentId',
        // ---------------Where confused
        // match: { postId: _id },
        select: 'comment',
        options: {limit: 5}
      })
      .sort({createdAt: 'desc'})
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);

      res.send({response: data});
      });
    });
});


//when generating new docs
//getting this from bodyparser from button submit

 const newComment = new Comments({
    comment: req.body.userComment,
    articleId: req.body.id
});

  newComment.save();
  
 const newArticle = new Article({
    topic: data.topic,
    title: data.title,
    url: data.url
});
    newArticle.save();
```

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const Comments = require('./comments');

const PostSchema = new Schema({
  topic: String,
  title: String,
  url: String,
  commentId: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comments'}]
},
{
  timestamps: true
});


const Post = mongoose.model('Post', ArticleSchema);

module.exports = Post;
```

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const Post = require('./articles');

const CommentSchema = new Schema({
  comment: String,
  articleId: String
},
{
  timestamps: true
});

const Comments = mongoose.model('Comments', CommentSchema);

module.exports = Comments;
```

Comment: Not really that clear what you are asking here. Have you actually saved the comment `_id` within the array on the `Post`? That is what you have actually asked the schema to do if you don't understand that part. So the general idea is that there is an "array of `ObjectId` values pointing to the `_id` values of the items in the `Comment` collection stored within the `Post`.

Comment: Sorry first I want to find all the posts inside of the post collections, then i want to grab all of the comments for each of the posts found. however i want to only match the comments that have the same id as the post. ill edit to make it more clear